# Strange space between Figure's numbers and commas (Figure. 1 , shows.....)

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I am getting a wrong space appearing between my Figure or Table cross-references' numbers, and my next character (word, comma, etc.), as hyphened below:

This is the code from Wiley:

```
\documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}

\articletype{Article Type}%

\received{26 April 2016}
\revised{6 June 2016}
\accepted{6 June 2016}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}


The Figure \ref{fig2}

\begin{figure*}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=342pt,height=9pc,draft]{empty}}
\caption{This is the sample figure caption.\label{fig2}}
\end{figure*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you add a small compilable document to your question that shows this behavior? Preferably with a screenshot so we can check if the issue can be reproduced from the code. It may however be a viewer problem, first check if a different zoom level or a different pdf viewer makes any difference in how much space is displayed.

Comment: Dear Marijn, I have uploaded all my preamble commands and the final citation shape as it appears in my text. Would appreciate any advices...

Comment: In your code I added `\label{myfig}` to the figure and `In Figure \ref{myfig}, the ela` to the main document, and I get normal spacing (using the Wiley class from https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/14678640/homepage/custom_copy.htm). So your problem is not yet reproducible, please provide the code that actually produces the wrong output when it is copy-pasted and compiled. Also try if adding the code as I did results in the wrong output for you or not.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. One more advice on using the site: if you select the code when editing and press the code button (looks like `{}`) then the code will be formatted as code, with syntax highlighting in a monospace font with gray background.

Comment: But also: this code still does not reproduce the issue, at least not when I try it. The red box around `1` is the correct size, i.e., fits closely around the number 1. Also when I change the code to add something after the reference, such as `\ref{fig2}, and` or `\ref{fig2}x`, then the new text (the comma or the `x`) is added directly after the number 1 without a gap. So, can you confirm that the issue appears for you when using this exact code?

Comment: Since you mention you use TeXstudio, does it happen only in the internal viewer or also when you open the pdf with an external viewer such as Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 3):

Update: I found the command causing the issue described by user221420! In line 530 of the .cls file provided by Wiley the follwoing code modifies the custom behaviour:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}\enspace }
```

\enspace (adds 0.5 em) is the culprit. The same is done in line 532 for tables. Though I'm not sure if messing with this is advisable, as it seems to be intended behaviour, changing it from inside the .tex document (i.e. without touching the .cls file) is possible by placing

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{enspace}{\enspace}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=enspace, skip=10pt, labelfont=bf}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{figure}}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=enspace, skip=10pt, labelfont=bf}
```

in the preamble. Sorry for the non-answer below, I'm new here and didn't have the necessary reputation for a comment on the reproducibility. So I made it an answer and added my own findings.

Original Post:

Opposite to Marijn, I could replicate the exact behaviour user221420 reports using his MWE (and adding some actual text after the reference call). I have the same problem in a document where I have to use WileyNJD-v2 and after a few hours of tinkering around I finally gave up as the problem seems to originate from the WileyNJD-v2.cls file itself and changing it isn't an option. I'd still like to know what exactly causes the issue, so here are my findings so far:

- The problem is not due to the compiler. I tested Texmaker, TeXstudio
  and TeXworks.
- Zoom levels and the pdf viewer don't have an effect. All internal
  viewers and the Adobe Acrobat Reader show the same issue.
- Adding the \label{...} function inside the \caption{} or after it
  doesn't make a difference.
- Ending the respective line containing \label{...} with %% doesn't
  make a difference.
- Ending every line in the .cls file with % doesn't make a difference

I also observed that the compiled demonstration file provided by Wiley (AMA-stix/Documents/wileyNJD-Doc.pdf under the link provided by Marijn) has the same problem (see p. 2).

Once again, changing the WileyNJD-v2.cls file isn't an option and hardcoding a negative space in there isn't either as it might mess up the publishers typesetting. However, if one could find out what exactly is causing the issue it might be possible to fix it from inside the .tex file so any helpful comments regarding this would be highly arreciated.

P.S.: I'm using MikTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  This seems like it isn't actually an answer.  It might be better to post it as its own question, linking back to this one.  If you could provide us with a minimal working example that reproduces the problem, then we might have something to go with.  If you put `\listfiles` as the first command (before the `\documentclass`, even), then the end of the log will show you version information that would be useful.

Comment: I just got the document class from Wiley, and it does not have the `\enspace` error (except in a comment). It puts horizontal spacing (9pt) in `\fnum@figure` where belongs. Perhaps the class was updated?

Comment: It appears there was indeed a stealth update. Slightly frustrating, as I tried making sure I'm having the same file by checking the date provided in the cls preamble where it states "2017/06/23 v0.2 Standard LaTeX document class for Journal" in both documents. This is particularly strange as the spacing in the figure and table captions is not the same as in what appears to be the older version so that there is a visual difference. This is particularly troublesome as every Wiley journal distributes their own copy of this supposedly identical file.

Comment: I keeps getting better: thought I'd check a typeset example of the specific Journal I'm preparing an article for (Journal of Biophotonics) to see if I can find out which version the typesetter over there is using so that I could adhere to that. Well, turns out he/she came up with his/her own workarund and used what appears to be a \quad as spacer in the caption...